# Does Yoast SEO put "Focus Keyword" as H1 Tag?

Tags: meta-tags

At the outset thanks you all for not assuming that I do coding. My question is related to my very simple and a first-timer's website http://enconengineers.in/ written in Drupal-8 with Zircon theme. While checking my Content with Yoast SEO module, it asks for "Focus Keyword" for the H1-Tag. It also red-flags about missing H-2 Tag. My query is does Yoast SEO automatically put the focus keyword as a H1-Tag in the content?

If not, shall appreciate if anyone can share the Steps/ways/setting-processes using which I can globally (for my website) define H1-Tag (which will always be a keyword (different for each content) in each content's Title Tag) and H2-Tag (which will be in 1st/2nd paragraph of each content) for all the content pages?

Answer (score 0):

Without having to heavily modify the theme itself the most direct approach to solving your problem to have a better Yoast score would be to install and use the [Meta Tag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module in Drupal 8.

It sets many typical metatags in the head portion of every HTML page Drupal renders for visitors. If you need a custom meta tag for h1 focus word or h2 related items, I'm sure the metatag API supports creating your own metatags that can make use of [Tokens](https://www.drupal.org/project/token).

Either use pre-existing Drupal 8 tokens provided by the Token module, or use the API provided by the Token to programmatically create tokens specific to your site that implement the functionality you need for a focus word or an H2 related token. This of course requires some PHP and web development experience, or hiring a web developer.